# New blank page in Zen-Cart

Tags: e-commerce, zen-cart

How can I create a new blank page in zen-cart without applying the template.
I want to create a page that will result only a JSON data...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a php file in your store directory. In that file, if you want to use ZenCart functions you can include them, like so:

```
<?php

include "includes/application_top.php";

set headers for mime type
set headers for not caching
YOUR CODE
echo $json;

// below is optional if you didn't create/edit session
include "includes/application_bottom.php";
```

Comment: just want to mention, if you don't need zen cart API's, you can just include 'includes/configure.php' and access db's, etc directly. Much faster.

Comment: what is application_top.php? What will be my url for that file?

Comment: the url will be whatever you call the file (eg, /store/mynewfile.php). That include above includes all the zencart functions if you want to use them in your php file. if you don't, just include the configure.php if you want to use the database login info.